# fanning records with left joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm experiencing duplicates/fanning out of left joins.

Table `Sales` has a number of brands, but only two of the same brand names with different pricings: `BRAND 2`.

Table `CSR Product` also has two `BRAND 2` brands, but for different states.

Table `Product State Package` doesn't have two `BRAND 2`.

I'm joining these three on `brand` field, yet I'm seeing for each `BRAND 2` I add to a table, it multiplies the size. How can I fix this?

I need all `Sales` records, hence why I'm left joining on Sales. This is a smaller example of a larger problem I'm facing where the first left join was **3020 records**, the second left join was **450,000 records**.

**My question is:** If I'm `LEFT JOIN`ing to get all sales records, why does adding duplicate `BRAND 2` to the other two joined tables multiply the sales records?

Sales:

```
brand   | pricing
----------------
BRAND 1    1
BRAND 2    2  <--- Brand 2
BRAND 2    7  <--- Brand 2
BRAND 3    3
BRAND 4    4
BRAND 5    5
BRAND 6    6
```

Product State Package:

```
brand   | state
----------------
BRAND 5    WA
BRAND 4    AZ
BRAND 2    MO
BRAND 1    VT
BRAND 8    SD
```

CSR Product:

```
brand   | state
----------------
BRAND 2    CT <--- Brand 2
BRAND 3    MA
BRAND 2    CA <--- Brand 2
BRAND 4    GA
BRAND 5    LA
BRAND 9    WA
```

Query:

```
SELECT s.brand, 
       tcp.brand as csr_brand, 
       tpsp.brand as psp_brand 
FROM   test_sales s 
       LEFT JOIN test_csr_product tcp 
              ON ( s.brand = tcp.brand ) 
       LEFT JOIN test_product_state_package tpsp 
              ON ( s.brand = tpsp.brand );
```

Output:

```
 -- Need all sales records
 sales_brand | csr_brand | psp_brand 
-------------+-----------+-----------
 BRAND 1     |           | BRAND 1
 BRAND 2     | BRAND 2   | BRAND 2
 BRAND 2     | BRAND 2   | BRAND 2
 BRAND 2     | BRAND 2   | BRAND 2
 BRAND 2     | BRAND 2   | BRAND 2
 BRAND 3     | BRAND 3   | 
 BRAND 4     | BRAND 4   | BRAND 4
 BRAND 5     | BRAND 5   | BRAND 5
 BRAND 6     |           | 
(9 rows)
```

With three `BRAND 2` in `Sales`: you can see there are duplicates for `sale_price` across the sales:

```
sales_brand | sale_price | csr_brand | psp_brand 
-------------+------------+-----------+-----------
 BRAND 1     |          1 |           | BRAND 1
 BRAND 2     |          2 | BRAND 2   | BRAND 2
 BRAND 2     |          2 | BRAND 2   | BRAND 2
 BRAND 2     |          7 | BRAND 2   | BRAND 2
 BRAND 2     |          7 | BRAND 2   | BRAND 2
 BRAND 2     |         10 | BRAND 2   | BRAND 2
 BRAND 2     |         10 | BRAND 2   | BRAND 2
 BRAND 3     |          3 | BRAND 3   | 
 BRAND 4     |          4 | BRAND 4   | BRAND 4
 BRAND 5     |          5 | BRAND 5   | BRAND 5
 BRAND 6     |          6 |           | 
 (11 rows)
```

Comment: Can you write what's your give an example of  your wanted output?

Answer (score 0):

Does it fit?

```
SELECT s.brand, 
       tcp.brand as csr_brand, 
       tpsp.brand as psp_brand 
FROM   (select distinct t.brand from test_sales t) s 
       LEFT JOIN test_csr_product tcp 
              ON ( s.brand = tcp.brand ) 
       LEFT JOIN test_product_state_package tpsp 
              ON ( s.brand = tpsp.brand );
```

Comment: Not really because my question isn't about `DISTINCT` records. It's about why adding the same `BRAND 2` value (`brand` is the column that the tables are joined on) in the tables that are `LEFT JOIN`ed causes duplicates in the `sales` table. `DISTINCT` would only show one sale price of `10` for `BRAND 2` even if there are more sales of 10 with `BRAND 2`. I need all of the sales

Comment: can you give example of your wanted output?

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure if I have understood yor problem exactly but if you consider tpsp.state, tcp.state in the result, the result rows are not really duplicated.